# R only lets me run part of a code. I get the warning "error in x : unused argument y"

Tags: r, maxent

I a trying to set up MaxEnt so I am following a tuturiol on YT titled  "how to decide which setting to use when running MaxEnt, as well as how to make a bias file"

I enter my occurrence points (occ) and stacked all my variables (env). Now I need to create a bias file.

i started with rasterizing my occurrence points

```
occur.ras <- rasterize(occ,env,1)
```

this worked. But the next code doesn't

```
presences <- which(values(occur.ras) == 1)
pres.locs <- coordinates(occur.ras)[presences,]
dens <- kde2d(pres.locs[,1], pres.locs[,2], n=c(nrow(occur.ras), ncol(occur.ras)), lins=c(extent(env)[1], extent(env)[2], extent(env)[3], extent(env)[4]))
dens.ras <- raster(dens,env)
dens.ras2 <- resample(dens.ras, env)
```

i get the error

```
Error in kde2d(pres.locs[, 1], pres.locs[, 2], n = c(nrow(occur.ras),  : 
 unused argument (lins = c(extent(env)[1], extent(env)[2], extent(env)[3], extent(env)[4]))
```

It does work if I take out

```
unused argument (lins = c(extent(env)[1], extent(env)[2], extent(env)[3], extent(env)[4])
```

but i am worried this will cause problems later  down the line. Is there anyway i can make the WHOLE code work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you made a typo? `MASS::kde2d` does not have an argument called `lins`. Perhaps you meant `lims=c(extent(env)[1], extent(env)[2], ...`

Comment: @nightstand Yes it was a typo. Smh. It's solved now. Thank you so much!!